# duplicate items from search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating an image search app where the user can search for an image. There is a problem in my code, suppose I search for flowers and press enter then flowers will be shown but if I press enter again then the same previous flowers will be appended to the already existing flowers. I want that if I press enter again with the same term then same flowers not be appended. I had to use spread operator because of `load more` button because that would load more photos of the searched item. How do I solve this problem of duplicate images? I'm quite new and been stuck in this problem since afternoon, any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import List from "./List";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

const LOAD_STATE = {
  SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
  ERROR: "ERROR",
  LOADING: "LOADING"
};

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.fetchPhotos = this.fetchPhotos.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      photos: [],
      totalPhotos: 0,
      perPage: 9,
      currentPage: 1,
      loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING,
      search: "",
      prevSearch: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPhotos(this.state.currentPage);
  }

  fetchPhotos(page = 1) {
    // e.preventDefault()
    var self = this;
    const { search, perPage, prevSearch } = this.state;
    const url1 = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=${page}&client_id=${appId}`;
    const url2 =
      `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${page}&query=` +
      search +
      "&client_id=" +
      appId;
    const url = search ? url2 : url1;

    const isSameSearch = prevSearch === search;
    if (search) {
      const options = {
        params: {
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
          order_by: "popularity"
        }
      };

      this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
      axios
        .get(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          if (!isSameSearch) {
            this.setState({
              photos: [...response.data.results],
              totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
              currentPage: page,
              loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS,
              prevSearch: search
            });
          } else {
            this.setState({
              photos: [...this.state.photos, ...response.data.results],
              totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
              currentPage: page,
              loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
        });
    } else {
      const options = {
        params: {
          client_id: appId,
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
          order_by: "popularity"
        }
      };

      this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
      axios
        .get(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          self.setState({
            photos: [...this.state.photos, ...response.data],
            totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
            currentPage: page,
            loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Enter query"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => this.fetchPhotos(1)}
          className="button"
        >
          Submit
        </button>

        <List data={this.state.photos} />
        {this.state.loadState === LOAD_STATE.LOADING && (
          <div className="loader" />
        )}
        <Pagination
          current={this.state.currentPage}
          total={this.state.totalPhotos}
          perPage={this.state.perPage}
          onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does not do what you think it does:

```
const { search, perPage, prevSearch } = this.state;
```

`this.state` has 7 items, so you are not defining those variables properly:

```js
this.state = {
  photos: [],
  totalPhotos: 0,
  perPage: 9,
  currentPage: 1,
  loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING,
  search: "",
  prevSearch: "",
}
```

Try this:

```
var search = this.state.search;
var prevSearch = this.state.prevSearch;
var perPage = this.state.perPage;
```

(and they're not constants, they're variables)

Other problems:

You have `url` as a constant, and never update its `page` parameter.  You are forever pinging as `page=1`.

Even if I fix that and update the `page=` param, the url is not paging as you expect.  It returns 9 images, then 18, then 27

You have lots more work to do.

Comment: I did as you said but the same problem is still there. please have a look at my sandbox, i saved the changes @GAEfan

Comment: how do I update the page number in the url? can you please show me? I changed from const to var but the page number is not even in the url

Comment: btw that's what i want though, first show 9 images, then 18 and then 27 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here, when you press Submit multiple times for `flower`, it goes to the 2nd branch of the conditional statement, which `photos: [...this.state.photos, ...response.data.results]`, that lead you to your unexpected behavior

```js
if (!isSameSearch) {
  this.setState({
    photos: [...response.data.results],
    totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
    currentPage: page,
    loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS,
    prevSearch: search,
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    photos: [...this.state.photos, ...response.data.results],
    totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
    currentPage: page,
    loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS,
  })
}
```

Solution could be simple, in your logic, everytime you press `Submit`, you request with `page` of 1, that's the main key, not the prev search, so whenever page **is equal to** 1, just fetch the result from scratch

```js
if (page === 1) {
  this.setState({
    photos: [...response.data.results],
    totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
    currentPage: page,
    loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS,
    prevSearch: search,
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    photos: [...this.state.photos, ...response.data.results],
    totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
    currentPage: page,
    loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS,
  })
}
```

Below is the forked codesandbox

[image: Edit crazy-germain-xk8ud]

Comment: there's a problem with this. suppose, I click on load more for 3 times when the website is initially loaded to load more photos for the randomly generated photos and after that we search for something like moon then those previously generated photos are there in the top and only after those photos, we can see the searched photos in the bottom